# NodeJS DocuSign Request For Access Token Using JWT Grant Flow Returns invalid_request

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I require my application to self-retrieve access token to perform remote signing. I have chosen to use the [JWT Grant Authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/) approach.

NodeJS Code Generate JWT Token

```
let jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
let fs = require('fs');
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./env/docusign/ds.pem');

let header = {
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
};

let now = Date.now()/1000;
let later = now + (1000 * 60 * 60);
let body = {
  iss: "806eb2f5-8233-408d-9f6f-586699e316be",
  sub: "6ceb4b30-10fb-4e4f-96d0-916b7c844726",
  iat: now,
  exp: later,
  aud: "account-d.docusign.com",
  scope: "signature impersonation",
};

header = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(header)).toString('base64');
body = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(body)).toString('base64');

let payload = header + "." + body;
let token = jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, { algorithm: "RS256" });
console.log("token", token);
```

I used the token to send POST Request to:
[image]

And gotten a response:
[image]

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions. Thank you!

Comment: You might plug an assertion into a JWT interpretation tool like https://jwt.io to confirm it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use the DocuSign SDK instead since it has an easy to use JWT grant method.

But if you want to roll your own, compare your software with the [SDK's JWT source](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client/blob/master/src/ApiClient.js#L910).

### Added

Also, it looks like jwt.sign takes care of the header. So try changing

```
header = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(header)).toString('base64');
body = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(body)).toString('base64');

let payload = header + "." + body;
let token = jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, { algorithm: "RS256" });
console.log("token", token);
```

### To:

```
let token = jwt.sign(body, privateKey, { algorithm: "RS256" });
console.log("token", token);
```

See the [SDK source](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client/blob/0db0227a2ef43157fa923c977a1cf4fb6622e10e/src/ApiClient.js#L62)

Comment: Many thanks! I followed the Node.js code examples and made it work.